# if para de aviso en PHP al no encontrar registros

Tags: php, html5

buen día tengo el siguiente código de búsqueda

```
<?php
include("./../../conexion.php");

    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $caracteres_a_reemplazar = ['-', " ", "_", '/', '%', '*', ',', '.'];
    $codigo_buscar = str_replace($caracteres_a_reemplazar,'',$codigo);
    $codigo_preparado = "%$codigo_buscar%";


 $sql = "SELECT codigo FROM espec_sellado WHERE (codigo = :codigo) and ( deleted_at is null )";
    $coincidencia_exacta_sellado = $base_de_datos->prepare($sql);
    $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->bindParam(":codigo", $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->execute();
    
     $output = [];

    $output['especificaciones'] = "<h3 class='titulo'>Jet-Filter</h3>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<table class='codigos'>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<thead class='codigos'>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tr><td class='codigos'>Codigos WEB</td></tr>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "</thead>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tbody>";
    
    while($row = $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->fetch()){ 
        $codigo = $row['codigo'];
        $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tr><td class='codigos'><a href='./../filtro/filtro.php?codigo=$codigo&clase=sellado&cod=1' class='link resaltar'>";
        $output['especificaciones'] .= $row['codigo'] . "[*]";
        $output['especificaciones'] .= "</a></td></tr>";
    } 
    
     $output['especificaciones'] .= "</tbody>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "</table>";

    $output['especificaciones'] = utf8_encode($output['especificaciones']);
```

?>

necesito hacer que antes del  while se evalué si existe registro de no existir solo  colocar no existe registro, esta es una consta de búsqueda que realizo  mediante un formulario  con un botón de búsqueda, he estado probando pero el php no se me da muy bien

Comment: usa `mysqli_affected_rows` https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que **siempre** quieres mostrar una tabla, sea con los datos cuando haya filas, sea con un mensaje de *No hay registros* o parecido en caso contrario, puedes recoger las filas de resultados dentro del `while`.

Me permito además corregir un error de ingenuidad. Nunca debes pasar a usar datos de superglobales sin asegurarte que esos datos fueron enviados.

```
<?php
    include("./../../conexion.php");
    /*
       Declaramos una variable $data 
       inicializada nula para recoger
       los datos de las eventuales filas
       o lo que ocurra en el flujo del código
    */
    $data=null;        
    
    /*
       Usamos fusión de null para obtener
       el valor de codigo, si existe.
       Luego, comprobamos la variable, 
       y usamos la variable
    */
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'] ?? null;
    if ($codigo) {
        $caracteres_a_reemplazar = ['-', " ", "_", '/', '%', '*', ',', '.'];
        $codigo_buscar = str_replace($caracteres_a_reemplazar,'',$codigo);
        $codigo_preparado = "%$codigo_buscar%";
        
        $sql = "SELECT codigo FROM espec_sellado WHERE (codigo = :codigo) and ( deleted_at is null )";
        $coincidencia_exacta_sellado = $base_de_datos->prepare($sql);
        $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->bindParam(":codigo", $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->execute();    

        while($row = $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->fetch()){
            /*
               Si hubiera filas, $data se llenaría
               con la información de cada fila
            */ 
            $data.= sprintf('<tr><td class="codigos"><a href="./../filtro/filtro.php?codigo=%s&clase=sellado&cod=1" class="link resaltar">%s[*]</a></td></tr>',$row['codigo'],$row['codigo']);
        }

        /*
           Si no hay filas esta condición se cumpliría
           y asignaríamos el mensaje de que no hay filas
        */
        if (!$data) {
            $data='<tr><td>No hay filas</td></tr>';
        }
    } else {
        $data='<tr><td>No se posteó ningún código</td></tr>';
    }
    
    /*
        Una vez definido lo que ocurrió
        con $data, creamos la salida
    */

    $output = [];

    $output['especificaciones'] = "<h3 class='titulo'>Jet-Filter</h3>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<table class='codigos'>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<thead class='codigos'>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tr><td class='codigos'>Codigos WEB</td></tr>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "</thead>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tbody>";
    /*
       Agregamos el valor de $data
       a la salida, dentro del contexto de la tabla
    */
    $output['especificaciones'] .= $data;    
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "</tbody>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "</table>";  

    $output['especificaciones'] = utf8_encode($output['especificaciones']);
```

### Post-Data

El uso de `utf8_encode` no es una buena práctica. Para asegurarte de que no habrá problemas de codificación, considera configurar tu entorno adecuadamente en los distintos niveles: HTML, PHP, conexión a la base de datos, datos en la base de datos. Para más detalles revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967) en la pregunta: *[¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59489/29967)*.

Answer (score 0):

la solución fue  usas **rowCount()**, luego de buscara pude resolver. gracias a todos por la ayuda
simplemente use la variable a evaluar ->   **rowCount()**  mayor a 0 todo esto en un condicional iF y listo  resuelto el problema

**rowCount()** devuelve el número de filas en canso de conseguir un fila muestra resultado en lugar  de no conseguir solo da el mensaje de no encontrado

```html
 <?php
include("./../../conexion.php");

    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $caracteres_a_reemplazar = ['-', " ", "_", '/', '%', '*', ',', '.'];
    $codigo_buscar = str_replace($caracteres_a_reemplazar,'',$codigo);
    $codigo_preparado = "%$codigo_buscar%";


 $sql = "SELECT codigo FROM espec_sellado WHERE (codigo = :codigo) and ( deleted_at is null )";

$coincidencia_exacta_sellado = $base_de_datos->prepare($sql);
$coincidencia_exacta_sellado->bindParam(":codigo", $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$coincidencia_exacta_sellado->execute();
    
     $output = [];

if($coincidencia_exacta_sellado->rowCount() > 0)  {

    $output['especificaciones'] = "<h3 class='titulo'>Jet-Filter</h3>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<table class='codigos'>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<thead class='codigos'>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tr><td class='codigos'>Codigos WEB</td></tr>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "</thead>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tbody>";
    
    while($row = $coincidencia_exacta_sellado->fetch()){ 
        $codigo = $row['codigo'];
        $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tr><td class='codigos'><a href='./../filtro/filtro.php?codigo=$codigo&clase=sellado&cod=1' class='link resaltar'>";
        $output['especificaciones'] .= $row['codigo'] . "[*]";
        $output['especificaciones'] .= "</a></td></tr>";
    } 
    
     $output['especificaciones'] .= "</tbody>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "</table>";

 }  else { 
       $output['especificaciones'] = " <h3>Resultados para:<span class='rojo'> ". $codigo ." </span></h3><br>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<table class='codigos'>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<thead class='codigos'>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tr><td class='codigos'>Codigos WEB</td></tr>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "</thead>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tbody>";
    $output['especificaciones'] .= "<tr><td><h3 class='titulo' >CODIGO NO ENCONTRO</h3> </td></tr>";
     $output['especificaciones'] .= "</td></tr></tbody></table>";
       
        }  

    $output['especificaciones'] = utf8_encode($output['especificaciones']);
```

Comment: Recuerda que los snippets son solo para código HTML/CSS/JS. No se puede ejecutar PHP en un snippet.